# How do I predict new rows from a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, lm, predict

This is open data. Please have a look at both the data and my code and try to tell me what I am doing wrong. Here is the data- https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzGPJ4-xoC1oUURaQXVrSFVJUkk

I'm just trying to predict the next 10 or so rows from that data but I keep getting errors.

Here is my code so far-

```
df=read.csv(file="sampledata.csv", header=FALSE, row.names=NULL)

df <- df[-c(21),]

start <- length(df) *.2

train = df[,start:length(df)]
test = df[,1:start]
#df <- data.frame(t(df))

train <- data.frame(t(train))
test <- data.frame(t(test))

#library(rpart)
#fit <- rpart(X1 ~ ., method='anova', data=df)

#View(df)

#predict(fit, type="prob")

#df$Prediction <- predict(lm(X1~., data=df))

fit <- lm(V1~., data=data.frame(t(train)))
#test <- data.frame(t(test))

#predictions <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=length(test), ncol=20))
#predictions <- as.matrix(predictions)
#predictions <- as.integer(predictions)
#dim(predictions) <- c(length(test), 20)
#test <- data.frame(t(test))
#predictions <- data.frame(predictions)

predict(fit, newdata=test)
```

I think that the problem may be in the `fit <- lm` part. I don't know how to fit the lm with a row. It only seems to work with columns.

Please show me how to make use of pattern recognition or something sophisticated enough to be dynamic and not just to have it print out something like the following (these are statistically the most likely numbers given `df`)-

```
[1] 24.849651%
[5] 11.065672%
[9] 8.293240%
[15] 6.753669%
[17] 6.621362%
[23] 5.995911%
[26] 5.845562%
[30] 5.424585%
[36] 5.298292%
[39] 5.460669%
[44] 5.376473%
[48] 5.502766%
[51] 5.635073%
[56] 5.629059%
[59] 6.038008%
[64] 6.735627%
[68] 7.258841%
[72] 8.197017% 
[76] 11.179937% 
[80] 25.174405%
```

Note that what it prints out won't look like the above. I structured that data manually. I need 3 to 10 rows of 20 predicted values that aren't the same and I need to see the probabilities for the numbers predicted as well.

Good luck and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, the expected value of the  `row.names` argument is logical (TRUE or FALSE) only in `write.csv`, look at its definition in `?write.csv`. In `read.csv`, the expected value of this argument should be, according to `?read.csv`, a vector of row names or index position of the column in your file that contains the rownames (first in this case). So read in your file like:

```
df1 <- read.csv(file="sampledata.csv", header=T, row.names=1)
```

Second, looking at your file, I would reckon that your columns are the samples (16000) while your variables are the rows (20 in number) so you have to transpose your data.frame to have your variables in the columns and samples in the rows like:

```
df1 <- data.frame(t(df1))
```

Then make your models based on df1, for example:

```
fit <- lm(V1~., data=df1)
```

By the way, make sure you read the R documentation on the functions you are using and try to understand the structure and content of your data as well e.g. In the above regression model, `V1` is treated as the response variable, and V2-19 are the predictors but I have no idea what V1-20 are!! I hope you do :-) cheers

Comment: This is not an answer and it didn't help. I'm trying to predict a column like X1 but I want to use X1 through length(df) to predict a new column. Any idea of how to do that?

Comment: Wait, I made a mistake. Please see the edit. I forgot that the csv file I created was already transposed.

Comment: @Poppins586 just one question, In your csv file, what do the 16000 columns represent: samples or variables?

Comment: Samples. It's a training set.

Comment: Sir, To get the desired result, your data must be in the correct format. Samples should run row-wise and the variables column-wise. Your question, despite the edit, still produces a 16000 column X 20 rows data.frame: because you have left out the `df1 <- data.frame(t(df1))` in my answer. Second, the data being predicted must contain all predictor variables specified in the `lm` model. Your prediction set above (which is in the wrong format in the first place) is an empty data.frame so there is nothing to predict, so question is, what do you want to predict???

Comment: I want to predict a 20 samples of new data. I see what you're saying about how the dimensions don't connect. So what I did now is split the data into a training and a test set where the columns are both equal to 20 and the rows are different dimensions. I'm having a problem now though. I can't do `fit <- lm(V1~., data=train)`. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'll rephrase: What rows in your original data do you want (a) in the test set and (b) in the train set?

Comment: I want to make a 90%/10% split, or maybe an 80%/20%.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to predict new values for your dependent variable (X1), then you will need to provide novel values for your predictors (X2, X3, ...).
However, your *predictions* data.frame, which is supposed to contain the novel values for the predictors, only has NA entries in it, hence X1 cannot be predicted from it.
It is not clear from the data that you have provided what the "next ten columns" (actually rows, in your case) might look like, i.e., what values your predictors might take.

You could, of course, simply re-sample 'novel' values for your predictors from the observations you have. But I do not see how the resulting predictions would be of interest to you. So, the first question would really be: what *cases* (values of X2, X3, ...) do actually interest you?